# Allow some cgroups to bypass vpn

Tags: linux, networking

I'm trying to write a script that includes or excludes a cgroup from a vpn, such that when excluded, traffic from the cgroup bypasses the vpn.

The cgroup in question is:

```
$ cat /proc/7425/cgroup
0::/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-flatpak-com.valvesoftware.Steam-7292.scope
```

the `7292` changes on every run.

I've found a few resources:

- [1](https://blog.fraggod.net/2021/08/31/easy-control-over-applications-network-access-using-nftables-and-systemd-cgroup-v2-tree.html): Doesn't quite do what I want and the cgroup name is hardcoded.
- [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/1128672/whitelist-cgroup-from-wireguard-vpn): This is a temporary solution

What set of commands do I need to achieve this?